# Execution failed for task ':app:packageLiteDebug', unable to find EOCD signature

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, signed-apk

The build error is occuring while building a signed debug-apk.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageLiteDebug'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

   Unable to find EOCD signature
```

Comment: What is your question? You can post your solution as an answer, but a error dump is usually not considered a good question. Did you see [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1. Clean and rebuild the project: This error can sometimes be caused by a corrupted build output file. Try cleaning your project and rebuilding it to see if this resolves the issue.
2. In my case, it's the debug apk in the build folder which was corrupted, so deleted the whole build folder and created a signed debug apk. It builded it perfectly.